# .NET 8 Blazor Server - blazor.web.js vs blazor.server.js Questions

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Previous to .NET 8, Blazor Server apps included `blazor.server.js`. With .NET 8, the [recommendation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-a-blazor-server-app:%7E:text=Change%20the%20Blazor%20script%20from%20blazor.server.js%20to%20blazor.web.js) is to switch from `blazor.server.js` to `blazor.web.js`.

I attempted that in my .NET 8 Blazor Server Interactive app, but experienced SignalR errors

[image]

Switching back to `blazor.server.js` has appeared to be more stable

[image]

Our Blazor Server apps are hosted on IIS and are behind a load balancer. We do not currently have sticky sessions enabled, but the following logic has seemed to have worked around not having sticky sessions enabled in the past:

```js
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            builder.withUrl("/_blazor", {
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: 1
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

My questions are

1. Is it still safe to use `blazor.server.js` in a .NET 8 Blazor Server Interactive only application? Will `blazor.server.js` get removed in the future?
2. Is configuring SignalR with `skipNegotiation: true` and `transport: 1` sufficient for working around not having sticky sessions enabled?

Comment: We have [migration guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#convert-a-blazor-server-app-into-a-blazor-web-app) here which mentioned `Blazor Server apps are supported in .NET 8 without any code changes`. I had a test in my side that if I only changed the project version to .net 8 from .net 7, the app still work well. Therefore, using blazor.server.js should be ok if the upgrade is not for new features in blazor web app.

Comment: and about skipNegotiation, I didn't found a documentation from microsoft which mentions it can be a workaround, although it is proved to be a workaround for not have sticky session, I recommend integrating Azure Signalr Services for your scenario as it would help manage all the connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Blazor team recommends upgrading Blazor Server apps to the Blazor Web App model when upgrading to .NET 8 so you can take advantage of the new features, but it's not required. Blazor Server is still fully supported in .NET 8 and you can [upgrade an existing Blazor Server app to .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/70-80#update-a-blazor-server-app) without making any additional code changes. If you do choose to [migrate your Blazor Server app to the Blazor Web App model](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/70-80#convert-a-blazor-server-app-into-a-blazor-web-app), then you'll need to make some code changes to your app in addition to switching to the new blazor.web.js script.

Blazor Server requires sticky sessions because it's a stateful model. If a client needs to reconnect, it should reconnect to the same server so that it reconnects to the same circuit state. The [SignalR settings to skipNegotiation and set the transport](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?tabs=javascript) will only enforce the use of WebSockets and won't facilitate connection back to the same server and circuit state. So, when using a load balancer with a Blazor Server app you'll still want to enable session affinity.

Comment: It does seem, at least in our environment, that something between .NET 7 and .NET 8 has affected our use of `blazor.server.js`. We have not needed to enable sticky sessions in our IIS load balanced environment since starting Blazor Server back in .NET Core 3 by setting `skipNegotiation` and `transport` as described in my question above. However, it appears now that we will need to enable sticky sessions, so I will take that information back to my team. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons to avoid blazor.server.js in .NET 8:

**Deprecated:** Microsoft has officially deprecated blazor.server.js in favor of blazor.web.js. This means it might receive less future development and support, potentially leading to compatibility issues later on.

**Limited Functionality:** It's designed for Blazor Server apps, not Blazor Server Interactive (which falls under Blazor WebAssembly). Using it in Blazor Server Interactive might lack some features or integrations intended for its native counterpart.

**Potential Migration Issues:** If you rely on blazor.server.js and decide to migrate to a different hosting model or update to newer .NET versions in the future, you might encounter difficulties adapting your code due to its deprecation.

**Consider alternative SignalR configurations:** Depending on your specific needs, you might explore other SignalR options like using Server-Sent Events (SSE) or Long Polling with sticky sessions enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chandradev! Can you link to the MIcrosoft documentation that mentions blazor.server.js is deprecated? I was not able to find anything in my own searching. Thanks.